# Laratrust : Users and Roles Usage

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a Laravel user. I am currently trying to use the Laratrust package for web admin purposes. For User and Role implementations I want one user to hold multiple roles and one role many users can have. In my opinion, the most suitable relationship is Many to Many Relationship, am I correct? Then, is the function I made right?

App\User;

```
public function roles()
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
```

App\Role;

```
public function users()
{
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

Then how do I display the two interconnected data in one blade file? Thanks.

Comment: There is no connection between view file and the relationship between models. Please explain what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Sorry for undetail question... after i made the relationship beetween the models, i want to pass the data into one file blade. How is the right procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define relations as `users()` and `roles()`. You can display all roles of the user with something like this:

```
@foreach ($user->roles as $role)
    {{ $role->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: There is an error: "Property [roles] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: @GrowDeuno in my example `$user` is an User instance, not a collection of users.

Comment: public function index()
    {
        //
        $users = User::all();
        return view('user.index',['users'=>$users]);

    }     This is my controller... i want to display two interconnected data in index.blade.php... what should i do ?

Comment: @GrowDeuno iterate over collection, for example `@foreach ($users as $user)  ////here goes code from my answer//// @endforeach

Comment: how if i want to display the data from model role. Forexample: i also want to show display_name from model role?

Comment: You can do this by using exactly the same code I've shown in my answer. Just use any of the `Role` model properties instead of the `name`